# Tokenize function not working in XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

I am trying to use the tokenize function in XSLT and it is not working

```
<xsl:variable name="stringList" select="tokenize('XPath,is,fun', ',')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$stringList">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is this anything wrong in this ? I tried this both in eclipse and in the [w3schools tutorial editor](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

Actual code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rg="http://www....."
    xmlns="http://wwww.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Temp</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:variable name="stringList" select="tokenize('XPath,is,fun', ',')" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$stringList">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Well, i was using the w3schools editor as i have mentioned in the post, so i could not see any error log.

Comment: Just tried again in eclipse, i don't see any error log.It just stop execution at that code block.

Comment: tokenize is an XSLT 2.0 function. I think the w3schools editor is only XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Hmmm, i have changed it to 2.0 in the version though, in code block, is there anything else that i am supposed to do for running in eclipse.

Comment: I am not familiar with Eclipse. You might want to add a tag for 'eclipse' in your question, and maybe edit the title, so any eclipse users out there can help.

Comment: @TimC Perhaps you can answer this question. So that i can mark it as resolved.

Comment: I've added an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenize is actually an XSLT 2.0 function, and so you will need to use an XSLT processor that supports XSLT 1.0. The editor at W3Schools is XSLT 1.0 only.

I tried your XSLT at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ as an example, and it works happily.

Comment: Nice tool. Shame they don't acknowledge that they're using Saxon, or provide any feedback button. Any idea who runs it?

Comment: No idea, I am afraid. It was just a tool I found when I Googled for an on-line XSLT 2.0 tester.